# How to convert floating point base X to base Y, where X < Y

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the process to convert between two floating point numbers. An answer that explains this process for arbitrary bases is preferred.

Specifically, I would like to convert from a smaller base to a larger base (ie: base 4 to 7, or base 7 to 9) for floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide how many digits each representation will have, and you also need to decide what the base will be for the exponent (presumably it will be the same as the base for the mantissa). Once you decide that, all you have to do is, for example, to convert from base $k$ to base 7 then keep computing powers of 7 until you get the largest one less than or equal to your number, then subtract that power of 7 and repeat. (assuming your number is non-negative)

Comment: Your answer makes sense for integers, but I don't follow how to convert the decimal numbers in a floating point number.

Comment: @Sco The position of the decimal point is irrelevant, in floating point you have $a. b_1 b_2 b_3 \cdots b_n \times k^m$ where the $a$ and $b_i$ are in base $k$ and $m$ is some integer within a range. You can manipulate such expressions as I described, at least up to floating point arithmetic error.